# Textract APi Call using C#.net

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-textract

I'm looking for sample C#.net code to integrate Textract into .Net application. I tried for a sample but all available are with Java and python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C# .Net wrapper for extracting Key-Value Pairs from a Form Document

This Github [link](https://github.com/kinjalpgor/AWS-Textract-Key-Value-Pair-Demo-CSharp#aws-textract-key-value-pair-demo-csharp) might be useful to all of you.

Comment: Just as a heads up to anyone else that comes across this the referenced libraries in that repo seem to indicate that they're only for aws customers "that are officially part of the Amazon Textract Preview program. If you are not officially part of the Amazon Textract program THIS WILL NOT WORK.".

Comment: It does still say the text above, but I am not a member of the "Textract Preview Program" and it works fine for me. I suspect this text is just out of date since Textract came out of beta.